# porque me sale error en typescript pero me funciona bien?

Tags: typescript, angular4

```
function MiDecorador(paramtro1:string){
    console.log(paramtro1); 
    alert("Simplemente un decorador es una funcion que se aplica a una clase xD"); 
} 


@MiDecorador("Mostrar esto ok") 
class Computadoras{ 
    constructor(public nombre:string){}
    }
```

porque me sale un error osea una linea roja abajo y segun el error es :

> Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an
>   expression.   Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
>   signature. Type 'void' has no compatible call signatures.

eso me sale pero la verdad que me funciona solo queria saber eso gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**Los decoradores de Clase**, devén tener un retorno `void`(vacio) o compatible con la clase, en este caso compatible con `Computadoras`, si es que retornan algún parámetro, el cual no es el caso por lo tanto agregando `:void`, deberia resolverse.

```
function MiDecorador(paramtro1:string): void{
        console.log(paramtro1); 
        alert("Simplemente un decorador es una funcion que se aplica a una clase xD"); 
    } 


@MiDecorador("Mostrar esto ok") 
class Computadoras{ 
    constructor(public nombre:string){}
    }
```

---

Otra opción podría ser mas correcta ami parecer. (que al final también terminas referenciando una salida void):

```
function MiDecorador(paramtro1:string){
     return funtion(target: Function){
        target.prototype.mensaje = function(): void {
            console.log(paramtro1);
            alert("Simplemente un decorador es una funcion que se aplica a una 
            clase xD"); 
        }
     }
}
```

A la cual accederías haciendo:

```
let computadoras = New computadoras("nombre")
computadoras.mensaje() // La consola te dirá "Mostrar eso ok"
```

Esto es mejor, porque:

> El decorador de clases se aplica al constructor de la clase y se puede
> usar para observar, modificar o reemplazar una definición de clase.
>
> Si el decorador de clase devuelve un valor, reemplazará la declaración
> de clase con la función de constructor proporcionada.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, pero me sale el mismo error le aumente el void para no devolver nada pero igual me marca esa linea abajo y con el mismo mensaje gracias :).

Comment: Mil disculpas, creía eso lo solucionaba. Igualmente prueba la alternativa, ya que es mas correcta a mi parecer, por lo que dice la documentación de decoradores.